# PHP PDO fetch returns a array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

```
$GetUid = $dbConnect->prepare("SELECT UID FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$GetUid->execute($RegisterData3);
$UserID = $GetUid->fetch();
```

why does it return array not a string ?

var_dump('$UserID') says

```
array
  'UID' => string '45' (length=2)
  0 => string '45' (length=2)
```

it should be

```
array
  'UID' => string '45' (length=2)
```

update*
what about the 0 ? where does it came from ? thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't specify a `fetch_style` parameter. It returns `FETCH_BOTH` by default, which is an array. Here are the options and how to specify it:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

EDIT: Also, it will always return an array, even if there's only one column, because a row can contain multiple attributes. You can use `FETCH_ASSOC` and then specify your column name to get the data, or, if you just use `fetch()` like you did, the array is indexed by both the column name and the 0-indexed column number.

Comment: what about the 0 thing ? where does it came from. thanks again.

Comment: Try doing your query again, except say SELECT * FROM users instead of SELECT UID FROM users. the result (say if you have two columns in your table) should be something like this: array 'UID' => string '45' (length=2) 0 => string '45' (length=2) OtherData1 => string '12' (length=3) 1 => string '12' (length=3) Where the third and fourth lines are the second column (the names and values are just made up by me)  
And there wouldn't be a StackOverflow if it weren't for newbie questions ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and thanks too for the link, now I know more options to be applied when necessary

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get just the column, you need the [fetchColumn()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) method of PDOStatement.

Answer (score 2):

The resultset is fetched line by line, even if the line contains a single column